# How te select records from table A which doesn't exist in table B

Tags: mysql

For example my tables looks like:

```
Table `users`
id | name
 1 | John
 2 | Wick
 3 | Doe

Table `already_selected`
user_id
   2
```

In this scenario, I need to take all the users from table `users` which doesn't exist in table `already_selected`. I am trying to do it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` as `u`
JOIN `already_selected` as `as` ON `u`.`id` = `as`.`user_id`
WHERE `as`.`user_id` IS NULL
```

This returns empty result. Where is my mistake? I red articles around google and seems that this is the way but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` as `u`
LEFT JOIN `already_selected` as `as` ON `u`.`id` = `as`.`user_id`
WHERE `as`.`user_id` IS NULL
```